# jQuery Datatable: filtering + dynamic changes in table DOM

Tags: datatables, filtering

I'm creating a dataTable by adding the data to a table in the DOM, and then initialize the dataTable when the data is ready.
I'm using filtering, by adding custom hidden spans with keywords in the table, which works fine. However when I dynamically change the table's DOM with JavaScript to change the added keywords, the filter still uses the keywords that where in the table's DOM at the initialization.

I'm looking for a way to somehow "refresh" the table so that the filters will use the new keywords that has replaced the old in the DOM. Any ideas?

Comment: server-side data source? Can we see the init code?

Comment: The table DOM is created dynamically from a json source, then the dataTable is initialized. I also use rowGrouping and rowReordering.